# What can I walk through using Spirit Walk?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

Once again, the [skill description](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/spirit-walk) for Spirit Walk leaves a bit to the imagination.  What exactly does it mean that my movement is unhindered?

- Does it negate any movement slowing effects?
- Does it allow me to escape rooting effects or pull effects such as the Butcher's spear?
- Does it allow me to walk through enemies?
- Does it allow me to walk through walls created by "Waller" monsters?
- Does it allow me to walk through dungeon walls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spirit Walk is actually pretty straightfoward after a couple of uses. For the duration of the spell (2-3 seconds) you are able to move through any enemies, and remove all movement impairing effects.

This means:

Slow down effects are removed.
You can escape most roots, such as from any Jailer type elites.
You can walk through enemies (if you can click a free floor space).

You cannot walk through anything physical however. Any effects which create a game-object "cage" will trap you... ie Diablo's cage spell.

You cannot walk through the walls created by "Waller" elites.
You cannot walk through closed doors.
You cannot walk through walls.

Comment: regarding "clicking free floor space": there is an unbound (by default) command called "move." If you bind this to a key ("a", "mouse3" etc) you can get out of a mob without causing an attack. There is no "throbber" feedback like the mouse1 move command, but it works the same way (click or hold).