# What unlisted effects does Spirit Walk have?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

The tooltip for Spirit Walk hints at a single effect:

> "While in the spirit realm, your movement is unhindered"

Which I believe references the fact that you can use it to break effects like "jailed."  You can also pass through a [variety of other things.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67387/what-can-i-walk-through-using-spirit-walk)  However, anyone who has used this skill will know that it also speeds you up considerably.

I've noticed while using it that if I'm sprinting past monsters I have yet to encounter, they don't seem particularly interested in me.  However, monsters that I have already aggro'd tend to continue to chase/beat on me if I don't get out of their line of fire.

Is this "new monsters ignore me" observation a real effect of the skill?  Are there any other undocumented side effects of Spirit Walk?

Comment: Maybe we should merge with http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67387/what-can-i-walk-through-using-spirit-walk?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Spirit Walk](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/spirit-walk) renders you invisible for the duration, although your "old" body stays where it was, and monsters can continue to attack it.  If your "old" body suffers damage equal to 50% of your life, the spell ends early.

In addition to the invisibility, run speed increase, and the ability to walk through monsters, it breaks every and all effects that restrict movement.

It removes snares, stuns, jail effects, freeze effects, and any other effect, while making you immune for the duration (walls, however, still block you).

New monsters will "ignore you" if you pass by them, but are out of sight before the effects of the spell wear off.  In other words, you do not aggro new monsters while spirit walking (although your follower or minions following behind could, if they don't wind up warping past the monsters to catch up with your increased speed).

One other undocumented effect is that you no longer take any damage while the spell is active, so you can safely walk through area effect spells (such as the effects of bosses such as Belial and Azmodan).  Damage to your body after you leave it with this spell does not effect your overall health; it merely has the potential to end the effect early.  If you are surrounded, are taking damage, and use Spirit Walk at 1% health, then the monsters continue to attack your body *but do not hurt you*. If the continued attacks would do damage equal to 50% of your health *after* you cast the spell, then the spell ends, but you are no worse for wear than the moment you activated the spell.

As an example, I used this spell repeatedly on Belial.  If I was too close to one of the green pools indicating that he's going to take a swing at me, I'd pop Spirit Walk.  His attack would hit my body, ending the Spirit Walk early, but *I would take no damage from the attack*.

Another major, **major** benefit to this spell is that you can pick up health globes while under its effects.  This means that you can safely run through champion packs, rares, and uniques/bosses while low on health to snag some much-needed healing that would otherwise be far too dangerous to pick up (e.g. in the middle of multiple arcane lazers, molten magma trails, etc.).

Comment: So I suppose if I'm surrounded, this isn't going to immediately stop me from taking damage, since the enemies are essentially going to continue beating on my (now empty) corporeal form, at least until the walk effect ends?

Comment: Damage to your (now empty) corporeal form does not transfer to you. The only risk is that your body is taking enough damage that it will end the Spirit Walk before you can get away from the enemies.

Answer (score 1):

It grants 50% movement speed
You can't avoid Diablo Claws from the floor
u can pass through the walls of the champions

For an other exemple of dodging damages when you got grabbed by the butcher he will hit you very bad just after and with spirit walk you can dodge this hit but it ends it instantly the walk :-p

Question : 50% current life or max life ?